# Table border line is missing

Tags: latex, tabular, tex, pdflatex

I am trying to draw table in latex but when I compile my latex file it misses one boarder line of the table as you can see in this image. I have tried all possible way but no luck if any one can help. Here is the image that shows missing boarder line in bottom

[image]

and this is my code that i use to generate table

```latex
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Feature   Extraction                         & Feature selection                     & classifier & Accuracy & precision & recall \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{GLCM, GLDM, Texture Feature} & \multirow{7}{*}{X}                    & SVM        & 89.02    & 86.36     & 77.24  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & DT         & 85.37    & 75        & 80.49  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & SVM-RBF    & 92.68    & 94.57     & 70.73  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & LR         & 89.02    & 80.34     & 76.42  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & NB         & 68.7     & 78.95     & 48.78  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & KNN        & 92.28    & 93.4      & 80.49  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & Rf         & 87.4     & 98.94     & 75.61  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{7}{*}{PCA}                  & SVM        & 59.35    & 82.5      & 26.83  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & DT         & 61.38    & 60.53     & 56.1   \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & SVM-RBF    & 64.63    & 81.25     & 42.28  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & LR         & 57.72    & 80.39     & 33.33  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & NB         & 60.16    & 71.19     & 34.15  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & KNN        & 60.57    & 57.84     & 47.97  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 64.63    & 78.21     & 49.59  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{7}{*}{Univariate selection} & SVM        & 84.55    & 78.02     & 57.72  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & DT         & 80.89    & 71.12     & 72.36  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & SVM-RBF    & 84.55    & 78.16     & 55.28  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & LR         & 82.52    & 78.57     & 62.6   \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & NB         & 70.73    & 83.33     & 44.72  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & KNN        & 83.74    & 69.49     & 66.67  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 80.08    & 75.51     & 60.16  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hi! Your other tikz question was migrated on [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/): some of the top world experts of LaTeX write in there and you will more likeky find the best technical advice on that site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last `\cline{2-6}` must be a `\hline` command instead. Then you're ok :)